# How do I delete banned characters from a string more than once in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to create a script that will reduce, for example, "Hello. I had a great day today!" to "helloihadagreatdaytoday". So far I have only managed to convert the text to lower case :^)

I have a string of forbidden characters.

```
var deletthis = ". !";
var a = deletthis.split("");
```

As you can see, it bans dot, space and exclamation mark, and turns that string into an array. I then give the user a prompt, and run the return string (q) through a for loop, which *should* delete the banned characters.

```
for (i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    q = q.replace(a[i], "");
}
```

However, this only bans one instance of that character in a string. So if I type "That is nice... Very nice!!!", it would return as "Thatis nice.. Very nice!!".

Any help is appreciated :)!

Comment: This answer should explain nicely: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17606289/769971

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression for this.

```
deletthis.replace(/ /g,'')
```

what this code does is it finds the whitespaces in a string and deletes them,

moreover, a quick google with how to delete spaces in a string would have helped

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression

```
a = a.replace(/[\.!]/g, "");
```

If you don't know the characters beforehand, you can escape them just in case:

```
a = a.replace(new RegExp("[" + deletethis.split(" ").map(c => "\\" + c).join("") + "]", "g"), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to remove anything that is not alphabet then `LowerCase()` for case conversion and then split and join to remove any space

```js
let str = "Hello. I had a great day today!"
let k = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "").toLowerCase().split(" ").join("");
console.log(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex could be shorter in this case because it's the same output, so we could use `|` that means **or** in a regex:

```js
var str = "Hello. I had a great day today!";

str = str.replace(/\.| |!/g, "").toLocaleLowerCase();

console.log(str)
```